# Why does Claws Mail included in Tails generate PGP keys with only 1024 key length?

Tags: tails, email

Why does Claws Mail included in Tails generate PGP keys with only 1024 key length?

Wouldn't 2048 or 4096 key length be more secure?

Comment: Insane defaults nobody ever looked at again probably. Any keytype with 1024bit length has to be considered insecure today. RSA/2048 is the minimum length with RSA/4096 bit is recommended for general use.

Answer (score 1):

An oversight. You should [file](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/bug_reporting/index.en.html) such issues as bugs rather than assuming there could be a sane reason for it :)